# How to access hashmap stored in session in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, aem

I am working with CQ5 for the first time, please help me!!!

I am setting key/value hashmap in session in jsp. Now my question is how would i get that hashmap in session and set it to javascript variable as key value pair.

My javascript is in different folder can i access jstl tags like the below code.

```
var hashMapFields = {
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${hashmapFields}">
    '${entry.key}': '${entry.value}',
    </c:forEach>
};
```

how can i do this using data-attributes.

which will be the good way to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work. Also you can convert you hashmap to JSON and store it in Session.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map .put("A", "1");
map .put("B", "2");
map .put("C", "3");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(map);

session.setAttribute("map", map);
```

JSP:

```
var map = '${map}';
```

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Thank you for the respnse but i am trying something like console.log("map.testId"); but its throwin me an error. how would i get my key and value in javascript

Comment: try like this: for (var i in map) { console.log(i);} or just for one value console.log(map['A']);